# Event Listener Not Firing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events, mouseevent

I am working on a Chrome extension, and trying to get a click listener to function like this:

```
var morelistitem = document.createElement('li');
morelistitem.setAttribute('class', 'more-list-item');
morelistitem.setAttribute('drop-down-nav-button', 'more-list-item');
navul.appendChild(morelistitem);
morelistitem.addEventListener('click', testalert)
```

In `testalert`:

```
function testalert(){
      alert("weeeeeee");
}
```

The li tag is created properly, but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: I just tested it in a jsFiddle, and it seems to work fine. Have you tried it in a regular HTML page?

Comment: Check if `window.alert` exists. Perhaps its not available in the extension context?

Comment: Is the code part of a content script or an extension popup?